# Shell Script not reading first line from test file

Tags: shell

My test file has following rows

```
30 * 1 = 30
30 * 2 = 60
30 * 3 = 90
30 * 4 = 120
30 * 5 = 150
30 * 6 = 180
30 * 7 = 210
30 * 8 = 240
30 * 9 = 270
30 * 10 = 300
```

and I want to read this file in loop and print anything after `=`. I also would like to print value in this format

```
Value is : 30
Value is : 60
```

so on and so forth.

The current logic I have is not reading the file line and I am not able to display output above format.

```
My current code:
HOME_DIR="/test/users/"
FILE_NAME="table.txt"
start_pos=10
end_pos=13
cmd=$HOME_DIR$FILE_NAME
while read LINE; do
 value="$(cut -c$start_pos-$end_pos)"
 echo "Value Read are : $value"
done <"${cmd}"
```

Any help would be appreciated!
    Thanks,
    Mahesh

Comment: Please add tag(s) that describe which environment this shell script is running in.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using awk

In awk, the last item on the line is called `$NF`.  So, we print it:

```
$ awk '{print "Value is : " $NF;}' table.txt
Value is : 30
Value is : 60
Value is : 90
Value is : 120
Value is : 150
Value is : 180
Value is : 210
Value is : 240
Value is : 270
Value is : 300
```

#### Using sed

In sed, we replace everything up to and including `=` with `Value is :`:

```
$ sed 's/.*=/Value is :/' table.txt
Value is : 30
Value is : 60
Value is : 90
Value is : 120
Value is : 150
Value is : 180
Value is : 210
Value is : 240
Value is : 270
Value is : 300
```

#### Using shell

In shell, we see that each line has five space-separated items on it. We read those items and print the fifth out again:

```
$ while read a b c d e; do echo "Value is : $e"; done <table.txt
Value is : 30
Value is : 60
Value is : 90
Value is : 120
Value is : 150
Value is : 180
Value is : 210
Value is : 240
Value is : 270
Value is : 300
```